# how to view full database in android?

Tags: android, database

How can I view the full database which I have created in android.
The program of the database is as follows-

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{

public static final String TABLE_NAME = "scorecard";
public static final String COLUMN_1 ="hole_score1";
public static final String COLUMN_2 ="hole_score2";
public static final String COLUMN_3 ="hole_score3";
public static final String COLUMN_4 ="hole_score4";
public static final String COLUMN_5 ="hole_score5";
public static final String COLUMN_6 ="hole_score6";
public static final String COLUMN_7 ="hole_score7";
public static final String COLUMN_8 ="hole_score8";
public static final String COLUMN_9 ="hole_score9";
public static final String COLUMN_10 ="hole_score10";
public static final String COLUMN_11 ="hole_score11";
public static final String COLUMN_12 ="hole_score12";
public static final String COLUMN_13 ="hole_score13";
public static final String COLUMN_14 ="hole_score14";
public static final String COLUMN_15 ="hole_score15";
public static final String COLUMN_16 ="hole_score16";
public static final String COLUMN_17 ="hole_score17";
public static final String COLUMN_18 ="hole_score18";

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "scorecard.db";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
//create database
public static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " + BaseColumns._ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_1 + " integer, " + COLUMN_2  + " integer, " + COLUMN_3 +" integer, "+ COLUMN_4 +" integer, "+ COLUMN_5 +" integer, "+ COLUMN_6 +" integer, "+ COLUMN_7 +" integer, "+ COLUMN_8 + " integer, "+COLUMN_9 +" integer, "+ COLUMN_10 +" integer, "+ COLUMN_11 +" integer, "+ COLUMN_12 +" integer, "+ COLUMN_13 +" integer, "+ COLUMN_14 +" integer, "+ COLUMN_15 +" integer, "+ COLUMN_16 +" integer, "+ COLUMN_17 +" integer, "+ COLUMN_18 +  " integer);";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.v("nikhil","Creating a database");
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.w(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(),
            "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
}


}
```

And to view the database currently this is the code I have, but only one field from the database shows up.

```
public class statistics extends Activity {

private DatabaseHelper dataHelper;

SQLiteDatabase db;

String columns[] = {"hole_score1" ,"hole_score2" ,"hole_score3" ,"hole_score4" ,"hole_score5" ,"hole_score6" ,"hole_score7" ,"hole_score8" ,"hole_score9" ,"hole_score10" ,"hole_score11" ,"hole_score12" ,"hole_score13" ,"hole_score14" ,"hole_score15" ,"hole_score16" ,"hole_score17" , "hole_score18"};


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.statistics);
    TextView tv;
    tv = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    dataHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    db = dataHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String data = data();
    tv.setText(data);
}

public String data(){
    Cursor c;
    String result;


     c = db.query("scorecard",columns,null,null,null,null,null);


               if (c.moveToFirst()){ 
                    for(int i=0;i<18;i++){
                    result = c.getString(i);
                    return result;
                }
               }




 }
}
```

Comment: What u want actually? Are u going display Sqlite table data or you r talkin about Sqlite Database View Tools?

Answer (score 0):

switch to DDMS mode and then go into data/data/your package name then into database folder .pull database from their and paste to any folder. then you can use sqlite browser to view your database.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/

Answer (score 0):

You can view Table structure and Data in Eclipse. Here are the steps

Install SqliteManagerPlugin for Eclipse. Jump to step 5 if you already have it.
Download the *.jar file from here
Put the *.jar file into the folder eclipse/dropins/
Restart eclipse
In the top right of eclipse, click the DDMS icon
Select the proper emulator in the left panel
In the File Explorer tab on the main panel, go to /data/data/[YOUR.APP.NAMESPACE]/databases
Underneath the DDMS icon, there should be a new blue icon of a Database light up when you select your database. Click it and you will see a Questoid Sqlite Manager tab open up to view your data.
*Note: If the database doesn't light up, it may be because your database doesn't have a *.db file extension. Be sure your database is called [DATABASE_NAME].db

*Note: if you want to use a DB without .db-Extension:

Download this Questoid SqLiteBrowser: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/com.questoid/com.questoid.sqlitebrowser_1.2.0.jar.zip

Unzip and put it into eclipse/dropins (not Plugins)

Check this for more information